# PHP files in CLI - not executing from other folders

Tags: php, command-line-interface, linux-mint

I have a file "script.php". When I run it from the same folder, it runs well - "php script.php". When I try to run it from another filter like this - "php path/to/scripts/script.php", it does not run and outputs nothing. What is the possible issue here? My OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: Show code of `script.php` and error log.

Comment: PHP from the command line does not have any problems executing scripts in other folders. However if you are using `getcwd()` or including files using a relative path, then you may end up breaking things.

Comment: As it turns out, the issue was indeed included files. Thanks